# Is there a way to restore all deleted files of a certain type in git/github?

Tags: git, github

I have a large remote git/github repository of files that have been randomly removing files that I created before. I want to restore all the files throughout the repository history with a specific extension that have been randomly removed.

I tried looking online, but no one had the solution which was able to restore all files with a specific extension.

Comment: Look for git reflog in your git GUI. You can find the history point that you want to restore. Of course if you have not run git garbage collector yet.

Comment: There is no builtin feature in Git that allows you to restore files of a certain type. Instead, you use Git (only) to list the history and then *other* tools to list the files that you want to restore. Then you use Git to restore the files from the revisions that you have identified.

Comment: @j6t Just to be sure, isn't this exactly what I proposed in my answer below?

Comment: @VonC Yes, it is. I thought that OP is in search of some magic in Git as the question title alludes to. I only want to clarify that Git is not a magic wand.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by listing those deleted files (here, for instance, `.txt` files), using [`git log --diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203):

```
 git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="" | grep ".txt$"
```

Then for each one, you can git restore them, possibly with:

```
 git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty=""|grep ".txt$"|xargs git restore --
```

This is done locally, in your cloned Git repository.
It has nothing to do with GitHub, which is just the remote Git repository hosting service, where you can push to.

If the `xargs` does not work (because it would need the commit where the file was deleted, in order to restore it), you would need a bash script:

- first include the commit hash in your listing:

  ```
  git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="%h:%n%f" | grep ".txt$"
  ```
- second, process the result through a script:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  while read -r commit_hash; read -r file_path;  do
    echo "file_path='${file_path}' was deleted in commit_hash='${commit_hash}'"
    if [[ ! -e "${file_path}" ]]; then
      git restore --source="${commit_hash}^" -- "${file_path}"
      echo "${file_path}' restored from parent of commit_hash='${commit_hash}'"
    else
      echo "${file_path}' was already restored since its past deletion"
    fi
  done < <(git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="%H" | grep -B 2 ".txt$" | grep -v "^$")
  ```

Comment: Is there a faster way to do this? I have thousands of deleted files and I want to restore all of them at once.

Comment: @lumsum2 Not that I know of. A post process of the deleted files is needed. Can you test it to see if that would take really too much time in your case?

Comment: So I was successful with your first command, but the second command returns an error that 'log...' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: @lumsum2 By `git log...` I meant, the same `git log` command than the first: the `...` are to avoid repeating the all sequence, making the additional pipe command still visible in the same line.

Comment: I'm getting an error that says ```xargs: unterminated quote```

Comment: @lumsum2 yes, hence the second part of the answer, starting with "If the `xargs` does not work"

Comment: I'm getting error: pathspec _ did not match any file(s) known to git.

My script is in the folder where my deleted files are. 
```git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="%h:%n%f" | grep ".md$"
while read -r line; do
  commit_hash=$(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 1)
  file_path=$(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 2)
  git restore $commit_hash -- $file_path
done < <(git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="%h:%n%f" | grep ".md$")```

Comment: @lumsum2 You are correct, the script was not properly capturing SHA1 and filename. I have fixed, and tested the script to restored deleted files. See my edited answer.

Comment: I am still getting error, could it be my OS? I'm using apple silicon. Here's the output:
```git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="" | grep ".txt$"``` - Success, lists files deleted that are of extension md

```git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty=""|grep ".md$"|xargs git restore --``` fail, unterminated quote

Thus I try 2nd option. 

```git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="%h:%n%f" | grep ".md$"``` - success, lists deleted files

then for the last script, it gives me: ```restore.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `<''```

Comment: @lumsum2 What does `bash --version` return?

Comment: ```GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.```

Comment: @lumsum2 OK that might explains it. Bash 3 [has 20 years](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html). The command is meant to run in a bash 4 or 5+.

Comment: I restored a few files, but not all. Some parts of the process:

```was deleted in commit_hash=```
```was already restored since its past deletion```
```restored from parent of```
```fatal: could not resolve __```

Comment: @lumsum2 Interesting. What command did you used?

Comment: ```git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="%h:%n%f" | grep ".md$"```. Then I used

```#!/bin/bash

while read -r commit_hash; read -r file_path;  do
  echo "file_path='${file_path}' was deleted in commit_hash='${commit_hash}'"
  if [[ ! -e "${file_path}" ]]; then
    git restore --source="${commit_hash}^" -- "${file_path}"
    echo "${file_path}' restored from parent of commit_hash='${commit_hash}'"
  else
    echo "${file_path}' was already restored since its past deletion"
  fi
done < <(git log --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty="%H" | grep -B 2 ".md$" | grep -v "^$")```